# svg file not displayed by web browser

Tags: html, svg

I have a `graphics.svg` file having following code:

```
<?xml version="1.0" standalone="no"?>
<!DOCTYPE svg PUBLIC "-//W3C//DTD SVG 1.1//EN" "http://www.w3.org/Graphics/SVG/1.1/DTD/svg11.dtd">
<svg width="400" height="110">
  <rect width="400" height="110" style="fill:rgb(0,0,255);" />
</svg>
```

If I open that file from web-browser(Firefox, Chromium), the vector image is not displayed. Instead, the file is displayed in XML format:

```
This XML file does not appear to have any style information associated with it. The document tree is shown below.

<svg width="400" height="110">
    <rect width="400" height="110" style="fill:rgb(0,0,255);"/>
</svg>
```

Is this because the svg file should be embedded in html file to be displayed properly?

Answer (score 23, accepted):

No, it is because you have failed to specify the namespace for the `svg` element with

```
xmlns="http://www.w3.org/2000/svg"
```

See [the examples in the spec](http://www.w3.org/TR/SVG11/struct.html#NewDocument).

Answer (score 7):

You are missing the namespace declaration.

You need to add `xmlns="http://www.w3.org/2000/svg"` as an attribute of the root `<svg>` element and while you're there you might as well add `xmlns:xlink="http://www.w3.org/1999/xlink"` too.

There are some more complete authoring guidelines [here](https://jwatt.org/svg/authoring) which you might want to peruse.

Comment: Why set up the xlink namespace when there isn't any xlink content in the file?

Comment: because most SVG contains xlink and you just run into this problem again as soon as you add something that needs it.